# ExtJS4 render a group header template based on values from a store

Tags: javascript, dom, extjs, extjs4

I am trying to render a custom grouping header on an ExtJs grid.

I want to display the grouping name; in this instance the grid is groupued by today, yeaterday and last week.  This is displaying fine with the following code:

```
groupHeaderTpl: '{name}'
```

And the grouping is done on a conversion field in the model like so:

```
{
    name: 'dateGroup',
    type: 'string',
    convert: function(value, record) {   

        var stamp = record.get('sentDate'),
            stamp = Ext.util.Format.round((stamp / 1000), 0),
            formattedSentDate = Info.utils.formatTimeStamp(stamp, 'd-m-y'),
            str = '';   

        if (formattedSentDate === Info.utils.getToday()) {
            str = 'Today';
        } else if (formattedSentDate === Info.utils.getYesterday()) {
            str = 'Yesterday';
        } else {
            str = 'Last week';
        }

        return str;

    }
}
```

In the model there is a boolean field called *read*.

If a message is unread then i would like to show the count of unread messages in the group header template.

I attempted this with the following but nothing is logged to the console:

```
                    features: [{
                        ftype: 'grouping',
                        groupHeaderTpl: Ext.create(
                            'Ext.XTemplate', 
                            '{name}: ',
                            '{name: this.unreadCount}',
                            {
                                unreadCount: function(val){

                                    this.store.each(function(item, i, count) {
                                        if(item.get('read') === false){
                                            // populate inbox store
                                            // increment the unread inbox count
                                            console.log('unread');
                                        } else {
                                            console.log('read');    
                                        }

                                    });

                                }
                            }
                            )
                    }],
```

Is this possible?  am sure it is but am realtively new to ExtJs so still learning.

Comment: do you have unread count in your store or you want to calculate unread count on rendering?

Comment: I don't hold the unread count in the store.  Was planning on calculating whilst rendering.  Ideally i would only like to display the unread count on the Today grouping.

Comment: but, template renders row by row so how will you calculate unread count on rendering?